# Calling Modal in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have view named index and in this view I have two buttons. On button click i want to show a user a modal form from where user input their information but its not working.

My button code is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

and my modal code is on the same view index is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap css? have u include bootstrap js on it?

Comment: yes i added the following files      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: any error in console? you seem to be less 1 closing tag for </div>, please recheck again whether u miss it or just wrongly paste here

Comment: wrongly paste their... its their like that  <div class="container">

Comment: is working for me, please check do you refer to the correct version of js, https://jsfiddle.net/om12d6zc/

Comment: yes it is working.Thanks

Comment: how to give id of that button to link in below code    <a  href="#" class="btn btn-primary"></a>

Comment: you can convert it as the same as button, your hyperlink can have id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, edit the link on your bootstrap and jquery. I added the `~/` part on the links:

```
<script src="~/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For bootstrap it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

Lastly make sure your jquery javascript files are really under js folder.

And your bootstrap files are really on css folder.

Tested it and its working fine on my part:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you!!

Don't forgot to import all the necessary libraries.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```